# Mathematical Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Database inside it 3 tables: A,  B,  C

A : (Item , Qty, Loc); B: (Item , Qty,Loc); C:(Item,Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4.......,Loc16) ;

I need a function for automate calculation and update the values on C automatically in the following way:

Sum(A.qty)-Sum(B.Qty) where A.Item=B.Item and A.Loc = B.Loc; Results should be update in C in the correct Column : From Loc1 to Loc16

When any value is added in A or B, auto calculation should be performed in C. In C, items are unique. In A and B items can be found in many transactions in different locations.

Comment: Show us your attempt. We can help you polish your code.

Comment: Also show sample data and desired results.   Your question is almost impossible to understand right now.

Comment: A : (Item , Qty, Loc);    B: (Item , Qty,Loc);      C:(Item,Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4.......,Loc16) ;   Sum(A.qty)-Sum(B.Qty)  where A.Item=B.Item  and  A.Loc = B.Loc;   Results should be update in C in the correct Column : From Loc1 to Loc16.

Comment: When any value is added in A or B, auto calculation should be performed in C.  In C item is unique. In A and B item can be found in many transaction in different location.

Comment: Comments are not the place for important information about your question; especially when the text you've supplied *was* formatted (comments don't allow formatted text). Please edit your question instead. Thanks.

Comment: Any answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose you, better than creating Triggers that are much more difficult to follow-up, create a View that will provide the requested information. Be aware that I put part of the query, need to be write the same portion of code for fields from 3 to 15:

```
CREATE VIEW C_View
    AS 
SELECT  C.Item, 
        C.Loc1, 
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM A WHERE A.Item = C.Item AND A.Loc = C.Loc1), 0) -
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM B WHERE B.Item = C.Item AND B.Loc = C.Loc1), 0) 
        AS Qty1,
        C.Loc2, 
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM A WHERE A.Item = C.Item AND A.Loc = C.Loc2), 0) -
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM B WHERE B.Item = C.Item AND B.Loc = C.Loc2), 0) 
        AS Qty2,
        ...
        C.Loc16, 
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM A WHERE A.Item = C.Item AND A.Loc = C.Loc16), 0) -
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM B WHERE B.Item = C.Item AND B.Loc = C.Loc16), 0) 
        AS Qty16,
FROM C;
```

Comment: Is working the solution proposed? If so, please, remember to vote up and mark as "the response"